# how to hide background when clicked on overlay?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have following UI

[image]

When user clicks on trash icon in important note box following pop up is coming
[image]

Problem I am facing is background items like splitter, username and date are visible.

Here is css code for popup

```
   .discard-note {
       width: auto !important;
       height: auto !important;
       min-height: 110px;
       max-width: 280px !important;
       top: 100px;
       left: 13px;
       border-radius: 16px;
       opacity: 0;
       box-shadow: 0 2px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
       background-color: #ffffff !important;
       color: #f4f4f4 !important;
       position: absolute;
       display: inline-block;
       .title {
                padding-left: 60px !important;
                width: auto !important;
                height: 29px;
                font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif !important;
                font-size: 24px;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-stretch: normal;
                font-style: normal;
                line-height: 1.2;
                letter-spacing: normal;
                text-align: center;
                color: #2b2b2b;
       }
       .body-message {
                width: auto !important;
                height: 38px;
                padding-left: 26px !important;
                padding-right: 26px !important;
                font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif !important;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: normal;
                font-stretch: normal;
                font-style: normal;
                line-height: normal;
                letter-spacing: normal;
                text-align: center;
                color: #2b2b2b;
          }
 }
```

Here is html code

```
  {value.noteType == "Important " ? (
                      <div>
                        {this.state.showDiscard ? (
                          <div
                            className="discard-note"
                            style={{
                              position: "absolute",
                              bottom: this.state.clientY,
                              left: this.state.clientX,
                              opacity: "100%",
                            }}
                          >
                            <label className="title">Delete Note</label>
                            <br />
                            <label className="body-message">
                              All the information in this note will be lost
                              for ever.
                            </label>
                            <div
                              className="form-group row"
                              style={{
                                paddingLeft: "26px",
                                paddingRight: "26px",
                              }}
                            >
                              <Button
                                title="Go back"
                                className="small"
                                tertiary
                                onClick={this.getUserNotesdata}
                              />{" "}
                              <Button
                                title="Discard"
                                style={{ float: "right" }}
                                className="small"
                                secondary
                                onClick={(e) =>
                                  this.removeCustomerNote(
                                    e,
                                    value.noteTypeId
                                  )
                                }
                              />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        ) : (
                          ""
                        )}
                        <div>
                          <input
                            type="image"
                            onClick={(e) => this.discardNote(e)}
                            src="/assets/images/notes/trash-can.png"
                            class="Trash-can"
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    ) : (
                      ""
                    )}
```

Here is how it should look like

[image]

How can hide background content when popup comes ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you try to add a huge `z-index` value to `.discard-note`? Like : `.discard-note { z-index: 1000; }`.

Comment: I tried that its not changing anything

Comment: Could you try to replicate this behaviour in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new) please? :)

Comment: Parent element of `<div className="discard-note">` should have bigger z-index than the content below.

Comment: Adding z-index worked thank you. Initially I misunderstood it. @johanchopin